# Batch file runs on local desktop but not on file server

Tags: batch-file

I am new to .bat files but have been working on a process for two days. It is very simple and works fine on my desktop (thanks for a code snippet found on the internet), but when I try to run it through a shared drive on our file server, the processing does not occur.

```
@echo off
REM  Batch file to process daily flat file and replace " with empty space for upload into Access/SQL Server

ren C:\Users\Desktop\filejuly17.txt filequotes.txt

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (C:\Users\Desktop\filequotes.txt) do (
    set S=%%a
    set S=!S:"=!
    >> C:\Users\Desktop\finalfile.txt echo.!S!
)
```

I have had to switch the `ren` to a `copy` on the file server, but have verified that I can copy the one file to another using that process. So am assured that I have the path correctly. However, no matter which options I have tried, I am unable to have this batch file strip out the double quotes that are randomly in the file from user entry. We need to strip these out and replace them with empty spaces in order to have a data migration process then load this flat file into our database.

Thank you for any guidance.

If it helps, my laptop is running on Windows 7, the server I remote connect is running on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: You are using `!S:"=!` but you haven't `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the start of the file - are you running `cmd /V:ON` instead? (You need to do one or the other)

Comment: btw: you say, you have to replace quotes with spaces, but you just delete them (replace them by nothing). Intention or typo?

Comment: @Stephan - typo on my part.  I intend to replace the double quotes with an empty string (so just delete them).

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - I did have that in my desktop batch file and just added it to the server.  Thanks for that.

Comment: C:\Users\z085841\Desktop\finalfile.txt & setLocal enabledelayedexpansion

Comment: Now when I run the file on the server (they added in write permissions where they were formerly read only) it wipes out all characters in the file.